# Use 2 keys in std::map

Tags: c++

I was trying to create a `std::map` with 2 keys. I can do it with `std::pair` or create a struct and use it as the key.

In my software, there's a search function that is being called a lot. This function searches by the 1st or the 2nd key.

If I had about 1000 items in the map, I'm guessing it will take some time if I wanted to search it. So I thought that if I make another `std::map` that holds the 2nd key and the value is 1st key, then I can take the value and search in the other map to get the real value.

But my guess is that this will take more memory. What is the best option in this scenario?

Comment: Just trying to understand the post.  You want to search based on "key 1 and key 2", or do you want to be able to search based on "key 1 or key 2"?

Comment: @Atifm "key 1 or key 2"

Comment: That not what std::map or std::unordered_map are intended for.  If both keys are the same type, you could insert into the map for both keys.  If the keys are different types, maybe two std::unordered_map's giving the lookup from the keys to the value.  Also generally, unordered_map (hashmap) is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

**Brute force approach**

You can store your items in `std::vector` and have two maps: the first with your first key and pointers (or indices) to vector items and the second with your second key and pointers (or indices) to vector items. The problem is to maintain all three containers when your set is modified.

Pointers vs. indices: Pointers are dangerous as pointed correctly in the comment, but simpler if you're going to delete items from the vector. Otherwise indices are safer.

**Smart approach**

You can use [Boost.MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) container that was designed for cases exactly like yours.

Comment: @Slava: I agree, but if items will be deleted vector would need to keep gaps or suffer performance penalty of re-indexing (if we speak about indices as a safer option). anyway edited the answer to address this.

Comment: I do not quite understand how pointers are any different for these gaps. But for pointers you would need to rebuild your maps on adding elements when vector changes capacity, that' for sure.

Comment: @Slava: yep, I missed reallocation. would it be a rare case when `std::list` can makes sense?

Comment: Use `std::list` just to use pointers? Not sure, using indices do not have too much overhead vs direct pointers. But I would just use `boost.multiindex`

Answer (score 0):

This is an engineering decision that you'll have to resolve.

Multiple maps only makes sense (IMHO) if you know that the sets of key1 and key2 keys conflict.  Otherwise, why not just insert both keys into the same map, each corresponding value referring to your object?

You don't want to duplicate your object, so you might put them in a vector, and put the vector index as the mapped value.  Or use a map of key-to-pointer, etc.

1k items is not really that many, so I'm not concerned about the memory use here, but using a map instead of an unordered_map might be a concern (rb-tree vs. hash table).

Also, if you remove items from the map, you'll need to be able to remove both keys together, so be sure to account for that.

Comment: The items has uid and name , the search for the items can be done throw uid or the name , this why i can't do it in 1 map , also items number can be increased by  the user , i don't know how much item every use will input the 1k is just fot example .